Vite HMR not working with monorepo package
I'm working on a monorepo project using npm workspaces with the following structure:
monorepo/
   apps/web - (Vite React app)
   packages/ui - (React components built with tsc, no bundler)

web vite.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ["@monorepo/ui"],
  },
  define: {
    "process.env": {},
  },
});

The ui package's package.json:
{
  "name": "@monorepo/ui",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tsc --watch",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "exports": {
    "./button": {
      "default": "./dist/button.js",
      "types": "./src/button.tsx"
    },
    ...
 }

// home.page.ts of web app 
import { Button } from "@monorepo/ui/button";

when I make changes to Button in ui package, the full page reload happens in web app, is there any way to make it make HMR instead ???

According to docs

The Vite server watcher skips .git/ and node_modules/ directories by
default. If you want to watch a package inside node_modules/, you can
pass a negated glob pattern to server.watch.ignored

please try to use
  server: {
    watch: {
      ignored: ['!**/node_modules/ui/**']
    }
  },
  // The watched package must be excluded from optimization,
  // so that it can appear in the dependency graph and trigger hot reload.  
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['@monorepo/ui'],
  },

to vite.config.ts

It didn't work for me. What worked for me is adding resolve.alias: "@monorepo/ui/button": path.resolve( __dirname, "../../packages/ui/src/button.tsx"). HMR is working fine now. But I do not understand completely the reason behind.
